# Looping over object array and using c:if jstl in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am currently working on a small web app project. The homepage has a link that, once clicked, calls a servlet that retrieves data from a database (in the form of an arraylist of objects), adds arraylist to session(as customers), and redirects to a jsp where the objects (customers) are displayed in a table. There is a "more details" column where each row has a button which submits a form, to another jsp, with a hidden input value with customerNumber as its value and num as its name.

I want, in the second jsp, to loop over all customers and only display the one whose customerNumber matches the one sent from the first jsp.

Current code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% String hidden = request.getParameter("num"); %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Customer Details Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <c:forEach var="c" items="${customers}">
                <c:if test = "${hidden == c.customerNumber}">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Customer Phone</th><th>Customer Country</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${c.phone}</td><td>${c.country}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code only prints the table heading. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, was trying to access variable from scriplet directly from jstl tags. The following code works fine:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<% 
    String hidden = request.getParameter("num");
    pageContext.setAttribute("reqNum",hidden);
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Customer Details Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <c:forEach var="c" items="${customers}">
                <c:if test = "${reqNum == c.customerNumber}">
                    <table border="1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Customer Phone</th><th>Customer Country</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><c:out value="${c.phone}" /></td><td><c:out value="${c.country}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
<td>${c.phone}</td><td>${c.country}</td>
```

You can try:

```
<td><c:out value="${c.phone}" /></td><td><c:out value="${c.country}" /></td>
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem even after changing that line :(

Comment: For testing, remove if tag and try to see if it work.

Comment: Found the problem, see my answer